Why are gradients None for all variables in my TensorFlow Siamese Network during training?
I'm training a Siamese Network in TensorFlow for image registration. The network takes a pair of images (fixed and moving) and outputs parameters for an affine transformation that aligns the moving image to the fixed image. However, I'm encountering an issue where the gradients for all variables are None.
Steps I've Taken:
Model Construction: I've defined a simple convolutional neural network (CNN) to output 6 parameters for the affine transformation.
Loss Function: The loss function computes the mean squared error between the fixed image and the transformed moving image.
Training Step: I'm using tf.GradientTape to compute the gradients and apply them using the Adam optimizer.
Despite these steps, the gradients remain None, indicating an issue with the backward pass or gradient computation.
Model:
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

def build_siamese_model(input_shape):
    input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu')(input)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(128, (5, 5), activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = layers.Flatten()(x)
    x = layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    output = layers.Dense(6)(x)  # 6 parameters for affine transformation
    model = models.Model(input, output)
    return model

siamese_model = build_siamese_model((970, 482, 1))
siamese_model.summary()

Loss Function:
def registration_loss(fixed_image, moving_image, transform_params):
    batch_size = tf.shape(moving_image)[0]
    transform_params = tf.reshape(transform_params, (batch_size, 6))

    # Construct the transformation matrix for affine transformation
    transforms = tf.concat([
        transform_params[:, 0:1], transform_params[:, 1:2], transform_params[:, 4:5],
        transform_params[:, 2:3], transform_params[:, 3:4], transform_params[:, 5:6],
        tf.zeros((batch_size, 2))  # Adding two zeros for the last row
    ], axis=1)

    # Apply affine transformation to the moving image
    transformed_image = tfa.image.transform(moving_image, transforms)

    # Compute the loss between the fixed image and the transformed moving image
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(fixed_image - transformed_image))
    return loss

Training Step:
@tf.function
def train_step(fixed_image, moving_image):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        transform_params = siamese_model(moving_image, training=True)
        print(f"Transform params shape in train_step: {transform_params.shape}")  # Debugging
        loss = registration_loss(fixed_image, moving_image, transform_params)
    
    # Ensure gradients are computed for the loss w.r.t. the model's trainable variables
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, siamese_model.trainable_variables)
    
    # Debugging: Print gradients and their shapes
    for grad, var in zip(gradients, siamese_model.trainable_variables):
        print(f"Var: {var.name}, Grad: {grad}")
        if grad is not None:
            print(f"Grad shape: {grad.shape}, Var shape: {var.shape}")

    # Apply gradients to the model's trainable variables
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, siamese_model.trainable_variables))
    return loss

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

Training Loop:
for epoch in range(10):
    for step in range(100):
        loss = train_step(fixed_image, moving_image)
        print(f"Epoch {epoch}, Step {step}, Loss: {loss.numpy()}")

Traceback:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [18], in <cell line: 2>()
      2 for epoch in range(num_epochs):
      3     for step in range(num_steps_per_epoch):
----> 4         loss = train_step(fixed_image, moving_image)
      5         print(f"Epoch {epoch}, Step {step}, Loss: {loss.numpy()}")

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py:153, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    151 except Exception as e:
    152   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
--> 153   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    154 finally:
    155   del filtered_tb

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:1147, in func_graph_from_py_func.<locals>.autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1145 except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1146   if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147     raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1148   else:
   1149     raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/local/scratch/melchua/slrmtmp.43866248/ipykernel_12859/2770984432.py", line 18, in train_step  *
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, siamese_model.trainable_variables))
    File "/scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 633, in apply_gradients  **
        grads_and_vars = optimizer_utils.filter_empty_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    File "/scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/utils.py", line 73, in filter_empty_gradients
        raise ValueError(f"No gradients provided for any variable: {variable}. "

    ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['conv2d/kernel:0', 'conv2d/bias:0', 'conv2d_1/kernel:0', 'conv2d_1/bias:0', 'dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0', 'dense_2/kernel:0', 'dense_2/bias:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is ((None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d/kernel:0' shape=(5, 5, 1, 64) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d/bias:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_1/kernel:0' shape=(5, 5, 64, 128) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_1/bias:0' shape=(128,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(3579264, 256) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense/bias:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(256, 128) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_1/bias:0' shape=(128,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_2/kernel:0' shape=(128, 6) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_2/bias:0' shape=(6,) dtype=float32>)).

Example input:
fixed_image = np.random.rand(1, 970, 482, 1).astype(np.float32)
moving_image = np.random.rand(1, 970, 482, 1).astype(np.float32)

